# Make image larger onclick

Tags: jquery, html, css

hello i need to achieve this --->Make image larger onclick.  After different image is selected previous image gets on the size it was before the click and selected image becomes larger

This work's only after image is clicked again

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var small={width: "127px",height: "128px"};
    var large={width: "200px",height: "201px"};
    var count=1; 
    $("#weekly").css(small).on('click',function () { 
        $(this).animate((count==1)?large:small);
        count = 1-count;
    });
});
```

need to achieve that it makes image smaller after another is selected

Comment: All div's/Images have same id `#weekly`?

Comment: (Unless you need to make dynamic calculations about your size dimensions), then I would recommend that you only use JavaScript to handle the click event to toggle a class. The styling can then be specified entirely in CSS.  E.g. `$(this).toggleClass('larger')`

Comment: @AlivetoDie no they are different, but could be the same if it matters

Comment: @Raivis  id can't be same . class it's ok

Comment: @AlivetoDie sorry, i meant class could be the same if needed, but the id for now are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JQuery `addClass` and `removeClass`

```js
$('.make_bigger').click(function() {
  $('.active').not(this).addClass('non_active');
  $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
  if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).addClass('non_active');
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass('non_active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  animation: make_bigger 1s ease;
  width: 200px;
  height: 201px;
}
@keyframes make_bigger {
  from { width: 127px; height: 128px; }
  to { width: 200px; height: 201px; }
}
.non_active {
  animation: make_smaller 1s ease;
  width: 127px;
  height: 128px;
}
@keyframes make_smaller {
  from { width: 200px; height: 201px; }
  to { width: 127px; height: 128px; }
}
.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 201px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img width="127px" height="128px" class="make_bigger" src="http://www.lyricsmode.com/i/upictures/205882.gif">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img width="127px" height="128px" class="make_bigger" src="http://www.lyricsmode.com/i/upictures/205882.gif">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img width="127px" height="128px" class="make_bigger" src="http://www.lyricsmode.com/i/upictures/205882.gif">
</div>
```

Comment: You can chain function in jQuery `$('.active').not(this).addClass('non_active').removeClass('active');` and `$(this).addClass('non_active').removeClass('active');` and you don't need two classes because you can use `img:not(.active)` in css

Comment: Ok, it don't work because you have animation on .active/.not_active so :not(.active) trigger the animation on init, but you can chain the jQuery function to make the click smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Do like below:-

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var small={width: "127px",height: "128px",background:"green"};//background added to show you that it's working
    var large={width: "200px",height: "201px",background:"green"};
    $(".weekly").css(small).on('click',function () {
        $(this).animate(large);
        $('.weekly').not($(this)).animate(small);
    });
});
```

```css
.weekly{
cursor:pointer; /* for cursor */
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>if images are inside div</h1><br>

<div class="weekly"><img src="https://www.fusemail.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/industry-compliance.png?x12193"></div><br>
<div class="weekly"><img src="https://www.fusemail.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/industry-compliance.png?x12193"></div><br>
<div class="weekly"><img src="https://www.fusemail.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/industry-compliance.png?x12193"></div><br>


<h1>Or images are directly there</h1><br>

<img class="weekly" src="https://www.fusemail.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/industry-compliance.png?x12193">
<img class="weekly" src="https://www.fusemail.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/industry-compliance.png?x12193">
<img class="weekly" src="https://www.fusemail.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/industry-compliance.png?x12193">
```

Comment: @Raivis  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

pretty simple

```css
img
{
height:50%;
width:50%;
transition:0.5s;
}
img:hover
{
height:100%;
width:100%;
transition:0.5s;

}
```

```html
<html>

  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGGB4NFcYsTk8ZYe35_aT0OmJ2e-NVS0rKxaFX5lhDCUkCW9IRVw">  </img>

</html>
```

Comment: looks ok to me.+1

Comment: i can read that fella but random clicking is not fun as hover+transition does